# jQuery validate submit form ActionController::ParameterMissing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

server log:

```
`ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: comment)`
```

used `pry gem` gem params:

```
 <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment_name"=>"123432",
 "comment_description"=>"231424", "commit"=>"submit", 
"controller"=>"comments", "action"=>"create", "article_id"=>"5"} permitted: false>
```

I know the `:comment` should wrapper `coment_name` and `comment_description`

so on validate add submitHandler try fix the format error

click submit button the browser show:

[image]

jquery validate:

```
$(function () {

    $("form#new_comment").validate({
        rules: {
            comment_name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },

            comment_description: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: form.action,
                    type: form.method,
                    data: $(form).serializeArray(),
                    dataType: 'script'
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@article, @article.comments.build], remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, input_html: { name: "comment_name"} %>
    <%= f.input :description, input_html: { name: "comment_description" } %>
    <%= f.submit :submit, class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

comment_controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :get_article
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: "creaed succeed"}
        format.js { }
      end
    else
      redirect_to @article, notice: "characters is too short or name has been taken"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @article }
        format.js { }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :description, :article_id, :user_id)
  end

  def get_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  end
end
```

any help thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller expects

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>
{name"=>"123432","description"=>"231424"}, "commit"=>"submit", 
"controller"=>"comments", "action"=>"create", "article_id"=>"5"} 
permitted: false>
```

In your form, by declaring "name" attributes for the 'name' and 'description' fields, you are essentially overwriting the "name" field's name from `comment[name]` to `comment_name`. So just remove those name attributes from your form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@article, @article.comments.build], remote: true do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :name%>
 <%= f.input :description%>
 <%= f.submit :submit, class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>`
```